# Bot (V4) shows inconsistent results in diff channel for basic choiceprompt

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am getting inconsistent result for a basic choice prompt in Bot using V4  in different channel. Also when i enter invalid options, it sometime appends the option list in some channle. not sure, what i am doing wrong.

e.g in Emulator 
[it shows like this which is perfect most of the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkjRk.png)

e.g when i publish to azure web app bot, in test in web chat. it does not show choice in boxes but show as suggestion list and also appends the list of options after i enter incorrect option.
[see in portal  Web chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKSbY.png)

e.g in Microsoft Teams, it does not show choice in boxes but shows as suggestion list and also appends the list of options after i enter incorrect option.
[see here in Microsoft Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWysP.png)

My code is like below

```
    public MytestBotRootDialog()
        : base(nameof(PowerBICSSRootDialog))
    {
        this.rootChoices = new List<Choice>();
        this.rootChoices.Add(new Choice { Value = "Service"});
        this.rootChoices.Add(new Choice { Value = "Desktop"});
        this.rootChoices.Add(new Choice { Value = "Other"});

        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            PromptForRootChoicesAsync,
            RouteToSpecificDialogAsync,
            RepeatRootChoiceAsync
        };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(rootdialog, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(rootchoicesprompt));
        AddDialog(new ContentPackRootDialog());
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForRootChoicesAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var opts = new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Select the Area"),
            Choices = rootChoices,
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter valid Area"),
        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(rootchoicesprompt, opts, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> RouteToSpecificDialogAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var selectedchoice = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
        var result = selectedchoice.Value.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (selectedchoice.Index == 0 || result.Contains("service"))
        {
            var context = stepContext.Context;
            await context.SendActivityAsync($"You Selected Service");
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
        }
        else if (selectedchoice.Index == 1 || result.Contains("desktop"))
        {
            var context = stepContext.Context;
            await context.SendActivityAsync($"You Selected Dekstop");
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
        }
        else if (selectedchoice.Index == 2 || result.Contains("other"))
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ContentPackRootDialog));
        }
        else
            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> RepeatRootChoiceAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(rootdialog, null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have two issues here. As far as different channels behaving differently, that's expected. As far as the choices getting longer and longer each time, that's a bug. It may have been fixed recently, so please update your NuGet packages and let me know if it's still occurring

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Updated the Bot Builder packages from 4.0.7 to  4.1.1 solved the choices getting longer issue.  regarding the different channels behaving differently, what is the best solution you suggest? adaptive cards?

Comment: I don't know that it's something that necessarily needs a solution. What specific problem is the different channel behavior causing for you? If a channel doesn't support buttons then that's up to the channel and there's not necessarily anything you or I can do about it. Not every channel supports adaptive cards, but every channel does support text.